# Inserting Multiple data into MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am having problem inserting multiple data into MYSQL database. With the code below, I am only able to insert the data I have input. Let's say there are 3 questions and I must submit 3 inputs, it only submitted the last one.

```
 <?php
include('questionDB.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $questionID = $_POST['id'];
    $answer = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['answer']));
    $insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO answers(survey_id, question_id, answer_body) VALUES ('1','" . $questionID . "', '" . $answer . "')");
    if ($insert){
        echo "Success";
    } else {
        echo "Failed";
    }
}
$startTimeAuc = mysql_query("SELECT startTime FROM questions WHERE survey_id='1'");
$startTime = mysql_fetch_assoc($startTimeAuc);
$startTime = ($startTime['startTime']);
$endTimeAuc = mysql_query("SELECT endTime FROM questions WHERE survey_id='1'");
$endTime = mysql_fetch_assoc($endTimeAuc);
$endTime = ($endTime['endTime']);


$currentTimeAuc =(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
if( ( $currentTimeAuc >= $startTime && $currentTimeAuc <= $endTime)){
?>
<form name="auctionQuestion" method="post">
<?php
    $auctionSurvey = "SELECT question_id, survey_id, question_body FROM questions
                      WHERE survey_id='1'";
    $aucResult = mysql_query($auctionSurvey) or die (mysql_error());
    while($auctionRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($aucResult)){
        echo "<p class=\"questions\">". $auctionRow['question_body']."</p>". "<input type=\"text\" name=\"answer\" class=\"answerField\"><BR>";
    ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $auctionRow    ['question_id'] ?>">
    <?php
    }
    ?>
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Few points:
 1. your code is vulnerable to sql injection, use prepared data or SQLI/PDO
 2. All your questions and answers are given the same name that's why you get only one inserted. Try giving them different names (using -1/-2/-3 sufix etc.), or if I make this, I would have 3 questions and 3 answers in the same record in database instead of inserting 3 times.
 3. See below part. You need to add variables to both answer and id. Otherwise they are getting the same name.

```
    <input type=\"text\" name=\"answer\" class=\"answerField\">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $auctionRow    ['question_id'] ?>">
```

Comment: I don't get what you meant for Part 2. Cause I tried changing the names of the variables , the result is still the same.

Comment: See my edit. I presume your current db structure is like record 1-survey_id/question_id/answer, record 2-survey_id/question_id/answer...what I suggested is to put all 3 questions in one record as record 1-survey_id/question_id_1/answer_1/question_id_2/answer_2...

Comment: But I did when submit button is clicked. 

$questionID = $_POST['id'];
    $answer = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['answer']));

Comment: you are not listening, try printing $_POST['id'] and see what you get. all your input have the same name that is the problem

Comment: Sorry I am no good in PHP , still learning. Now I tried printing it out and I got only 1 result instead of 2. So basically the first one got replaced.From what I understand, having the same name will cause this. Im still figuring what you said about the same input name.

Comment: if you only have a numbered question, follow my suggestion to combine all questions in one db record and rebuild your code, something like $questionID_1 = $_POST['question_1'];$questionID_12 = $_POST['question_2'];and then down there write out all your questions with unique name of question_1 and question_2 etc. If you have many questions, you'll have to use an array. This is not about PHP, this is common rules for all languages.